# 403 Forbidden Error with Manually Generated OAuth 2.0 Token in Postman

Tags: oauth-2.0, postman, authorization, http-status-code-403, amplience-dynamic-content

I am encountering a 403 Forbidden error when using a manually generated OAuth 2.0 token in Postman, even though the automatic authentication of postman works perfectly fine.

I am trying to access third party APIs of amplience(a dynamic content management system) for content creation, which requires an authorization bearer header.

I tried adding the manually generated as well as the automatically generated authorization header with "Bearer" prefix with a token in my API call. When the token was the one which was generated automatically, the request works fine. But when the token used was the one generated manually, the request gives a forbidden error.

```
{
    "errors": [
        {
            "level": "ERROR",
            "code": "FORBIDDEN",
            "message": "Authorization required."
        }
    ]
}
```

Manual token generation details:
[image]

Automatic token generation details:
[image]
[image]

I have verified all the required details - client_id, client_secret and the grant_type. I have not explicitly specified any scopes in the automatic as well as manual flow.

I would like to know if I am missing any details as to why the automatically generated token works but the manually generated token does not.

Comment: The access token get from OAuth server, can't create by yourself.
This is [documentation](https://amplience.com/developers/docs/apis/content-management-reference/#section/Authentication). manual means call auth API by Postman and try to call other API? Token expiration is short some server, like 1 minute .

Comment: @BenchVue yes, by manual I meant generating the token using auth API and using it in the Authorization header of another call. The expiration time is 20 mins so that should not a be a problem.

Comment: Try use `Basic Auth` in "Authorization" tab of Postman. Username is "Client ID", Password is "Client Secret" instead of use  the 'x-www-form-unlencoded' at input "Body" tab due to your auto gen. screen say "Send as Basic Auth header"